# Formula to summarize the multiplication results of two columns if criteria met

Tags: excel, summarize

This First formula make half of the work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND("X",$A$1:$A$3)),$B$1:$B$3,$E$1:$E$3)
```

[image: Image1]

The result intended to reach in the example is 60, the given formula only works with one column, in this case B, so C and D is missed.

A second formula summarize what is needed in the above one.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X",$A$1:$A$3)))*($B$1:D3))
```

[image: Image2]

These 2 are the closest ways I can reach, can they be mixed?

Comment: what are you intending to do. If colA has X, Sum (B + C+ D)  * Col E --> sum for all rows???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can be mixed so

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("x",A1:A3))*B1:D3*E1:E3)
```

will give the right answer because it multiplies corresponding elements of all three arrays.

The arrays in SUMPRODUCT all have to have the same dimensions so this would give a #VALUE error because the second array has three columns while the first and third only have one

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("x",A1:A3)),B1:D3,E1:E3)
```

Comment: Your first example was what I was looking, thanks Tom.